# Need a .net API to produce PDF with the option of text rotation

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation

I am creating PDFs from xml I am looking for an API which also allows me to rotate text, Is there any API available for .net?

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: like i want to rotate text to all angels (360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are going to use the library [**iTextSharp**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), as suggested in another answer (iText is a Java library; iTextSharp is a .NET port of it), here's some examples. These are essentially stripped-down versions from Bruno Lowagie's book [*iText in Action*](http://itextpdf.com/book/index.php) from Manning Publications.

(Note that the examples are written in Java, since I took them straight from the book, but you should be able to easily adapt them to the iTextSharp library and C#.)

### Image rotation:

This is found in the book on page 155.

```
Image img = Image.getInstance("foo.jpg");
img.setRotationDegrees(45);
```

### Text rotation:

This is found in the book on page 351-352.

```
PdfContentByte cb = ...;
cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Some text", e, f, angle);
```

where `e` and `f` are translation values (the coordinates, essentially), and `angle` is the rotation angle.

Answer (score 4):

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/). It's Open Source and you can even buy a quite good book on it written by the author. (And yes, of course it supports rotated text.)

Comment: thanks, thats great, can you please tell me how to do rotation of text and image from itext? thanks in advace

Comment: Free text: setTextMatrix(), TextField: setRotation(), Images: setRotation() (or setRotationDegrees())

Comment: danbystorm, plz can you give me a working example of text rotation, i'd be really thankful, i figured out image rotation which is quite simple but cant find out the text rotation, thanks